# Exception handling in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, exception

Which is the best way to capture a exception in spring mvc. I am not getting the end to end implementation of the exception handling in spring mvc.

I have implemented  @ControllerAdvice. Can you please confirm whether I have implemented in right way to handle the exception.

Question:

1. How can I handle the service layer exception. Do I have to throw it to controller and then to UI? How it works.
2. How I can handle the sql exception in DAO layer and other exception like Numberformat exception?

Code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getDepositSearch", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String depositNumberData(
        @ModelAttribute("searchCondition") String searchCondition,
        @ModelAttribute("searchText") String searchText,
        final RedirectAttributes redirect, Model depositStatus,
        HttpServletRequest request) {

    String pageForward = null;

    try {
        List<MRPSDeposit> depositDetails = null;
        if (!searchText.isEmpty()) {
            depositDetails = mrpsDeposit.getDepositDetails(searchCondition,
                    searchText);
        }
        Map<String, String> searchList = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

        if (searchCondition.equals(ManagementConstants.DEPOSITDATEKEY)) {
            searchList.put(ManagementConstants.DEPOSITDATEKEY,
                    ManagementConstants.DEPOSITDATEVALUE);
        } else if (searchCondition.equals(ManagementConstants.DEPOSITNUMBERKEY)) {

            searchList.put(ManagementConstants.DEPOSITNUMBERKEY,
                    ManagementConstants.DEPOSITNUMBERVALUE);
        } else {
            searchList.put(ManagementConstants.DEPOSITNUMBERKEY,
                    ManagementConstants.DEPOSITNUMBERVALUE);
            searchList.put(ManagementConstants.DEPOSITDATEKEY,
                    ManagementConstants.DEPOSITDATEVALUE);

        }

        if (depositDetails.size() == 0) {
            redirect.addFlashAttribute("flashMessage",
                    ManagementConstants.NORECORDFOUND);
            pageForward = "redirect:/mrps/getDepositDetails";
        } else if (depositDetails.size() > 1) {

            Map<String, Map<String, String>> search = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
            search.put("searchContent", searchList);
            depositStatus.addAttribute("searchAllContents", search);
            depositStatus.addAttribute("depositDetails", depositDetails);

            pageForward = "multipleDepositDetails";

        } else {

            Map<String, Map<String, String>> search = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

            search.put("searchContent", searchList);
            depositStatus.addAttribute("searchAllContents", search);
            depositStatus.addAttribute("depositDetails", depositDetails);
            if (request.isUserInRole("ROLE_READ")) {
                pageForward = "readDepositDetails";
            } else {
                pageForward = "updateDepositDetails";
            }
        }

    } catch (InfoManagementException e) {
        System.out.println("weee"+e);
    }
    return pageForward;

}
```

Service layer:

```
   @Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<MRPSDeposit> getDepositDetails(String searchCondition,
        String searchText)  {
    List<MRPSDeposit> mrpsDepositDetails = new ArrayList<MRPSDeposit>();
    /* try { */
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",
            Locale.ENGLISH);
    if (searchCondition.equalsIgnoreCase(ManagementConstants.DEPOSITNUMBERKEY)) {
        System.out.println("finalal");
        mrpsDepositDetails = mrpsDepositDao.findByDepositNumber(
                searchCondition, Short.valueOf(searchText));
    } else {
        try {
            mrpsDepositDetails = mrpsDepositDao.findByDepositDate(
                    searchCondition, formatter.parse(searchText));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return mrpsDepositDetails;

}
```

DAO layer:

```
   @Override
public List<MRPSDeposit> findByDepositNumber(String searchCondition,
        Short searchTxt) {
    List<MRPSDeposit> searchResult = super.findByDepositNumber(
            searchCondition, searchTxt);
    return searchResult;
}
```

Controller Advice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
 public class GlobalExceptionController {

@ExceptionHandler(InfoManagementException.class)
public ModelAndView handleCustomException(InfoManagementException ex) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("error/generic_error");
    System.out.println();
    model.addObject("errCode", ex.getErrCode());
    model.addObject("errMsg", ex.getErrMsg());

    return model;

}

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView handleAllException(Exception ex) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("error/generic_error");
    model.addObject("errMsg", "this is Exception.class");

    return model;

}
```

}

Comment: Anybody can comment on this

Answer (score 0):

> How can I handle the service layer exception. Do I have to throw it to
>   controller and then to UI? How it works.

In both cases that depends on what are your requirements. There are cases when you will need to show the same page with an error message, also there are some cases when you need to redirect to another error page. In other cases probably you don't need to show any error message.

It's common to throw the exception to the controller then process it in the controller advice and show an readable error message on the UI. In the controller advice you can determine the page that will show the message and also log the error message.

> How I can handle the sql
>   exception in DAO layer and other exception like Numberformat
>   exception?

I would recommed you to use input validation in the controller. If you use it, then you won't get this kind of error. But if you don't have input validation you can throw the exception and show a message on the UI.

**Update**

You can leave your service layer as you have at this moment and process the exception in the ControllerAdvice. If you want to process the exception in the service layer you can do this with a try/catch.

```
public void myServiceMethod(){
  try{
   ...
  }catch(Exception1 e){//Every catch block can capture a group of exceptions.
    //Depending on your business logic, you can throw a new Exception, log it,     or do some logic.
    logger.log("My error: ", e);
  }catch(Exception2 e){//Every catch block can capture a group of exceptions.
    throw new MyBusinessException("Something ocurred", e);
  }
}
```

Then in your ControllerAdvice you need to process MyBusinessException and do what you need.

Comment: Can I have example for the this exception handling for service layer.

Comment: Thanks for the help reos.